# Clear Flink MapState

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to clear `MapStateDescriptor` value.

For example, I want to remove all old value of the MapState and then add a new value.

I know there is `remove` for MapState but I would like to avoid to give a key to remove a specific state.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MapState.clear()` to remove the complete map state of the current key.